# Swift HTTP Post Request returns HTML of site instead of JSON response

Tags: ios, swift, http, post, urlsession

I am trying to reach a site that should take the username and password given and return a JSON which contains information stating whether or not the login data provided was valid or not.
However, all I'm getting back is the site's HTML code instead of a response. I've tried the request with the same parameters on https://www.hurl.it/ and have gotten the correct response so that does not seem to be the issue.

I use the following code:

```
private func uploadToAPI(username: String, password: String) {

guard let url = URL(string: "http://api.foo.com/login.php"),
  let encodedUsername = username.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.alphanumerics),
  let encodedPassword = password.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.alphanumerics) else {

  self.loginButton.isLoading = false
  return
}

let httpBodyParameters = ["user": encodedUsername, "password": encodedPassword, "client": "ios", "version": "5"]

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: httpBodyParameters, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

  if let response = response {
    print(response.mimeType) // Prints "text/html"
  }

  if let data = data {
    print(try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)) // Prints nil
    print(String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)) // Prints the site's HTML
  }

}.resume()

 }
```

I fail to see where the issue is. I've also tried not setting the HTTP headers but that makes no difference. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: What is the HTML content ? that you have recieved

Comment: code looks fine to me, must be the URL

Comment: Can you use `request.addValue` instead of `setValue`. I think it might be replacing it when you use `setValue`

Comment: You are getting HTML because of your sever issue. Please contact to your server team and verify URL & Parameters with them

Comment: @Vinaykrishnan Just the HTML of the website. It's a simple login form with a heading so nothing much to look at

Comment: @user1046037 That didn't seem to do anything

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Alright I'll see what they have to say

Comment: after creating the request, print it and see if it matches what you want to it to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like not setting the HTTP header fields and using a string literal instead of a Dictionary as HTTP body data did it for me.

For anyone interested this is the code that now receives the expected response:

```
  guard let url = URL(string: "http://api.foo.com/login.php?"),
      let encodedUsername = username.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.alphanumerics),
      let encodedPassword = password.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.alphanumerics) else {
        if let delegate = self.delegate {
          delegate.viewModelDidRejectLogin(self)
        }
        return
    }

    let httpBodyString = "user=\(encodedUsername)&password=\(encodedPassword)&client=ios&version=5"

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = httpBodyString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

      guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error)
        return
      }

      do {
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String : AnyObject] {
          self.readLoginResponse(json)
        }
      } catch {
        print(error)
      }

    }.resume()
```